# Get Names of Subdirectories within a Directory

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to write a Visual Basic program that gets the names of all subdirectories within a directory, writes them into an array, and then writes the contents of the array to a dat file. I am however having a problem with the arrays not filling up with the directory names. Here's a piece of my code below.

```
For Each directoryName As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(appdata)
       allAppdataDirectories(appdataNameId) = Dir(appdata)
       appdataNameId += 1
       ReDim Preserve allAppdataDirectories(appdataNameId)
Next
```

The above code snippet is supposed to get all of the directory names within my appdata folder. Assuming variable and array in this code has been declared already, what is wrong with it? I know that writing to the data file is working because I have done it in another context in this program and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the directoryName variable
Maybe it also would be easiest to use a list insted of an array
Check if this solution can work for you :

```
Dim allAppDataDirectories As New List(Of String)
For Each directoryName As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(appData)
    allAppDataDirectories.Add(directoryName)
Next

'Finally, if you need an array you can use allAppDataDirectories.ToArray()
```

Comment: If you need only the name of the directories and not the full path of them you can use     allAppDataDirectories.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(directoryName))

Comment: Thank you for this. My program requires that I have the full file path. I will try this out and let you know if it works.

Comment: As a sidenote, I have not yet integrated the list thing that you mentioned, but changing the code so that the `Dir()` thing in my code calls the `directoryName` variable did not resolve the problem with the empty arrays.

Comment: You don't have to call Dir(directoryName). but, if you don't want to use lists, you have to do this :    allAppdataDirectories(appdataNameId) = directoryName